# How to order awaits in asynchronous method

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

```
async getRecords(): Promise<Records[]> {
    this.subRecords = await this.afs.collection<Records>('records')
        .valueChanges()
        .subscribe((data: Records[]) => {
            console.log('log before data saved');
            this.records = data as Records[];
        });
    console.log('log before return');
    return await this.records;
}
```

So my problem is, I need this code to be executed in the right order. The `log before data saved` is executed after the return. So I don't really get my data saved in time. I need a way to order the execution of the code so that the function returns the records in my `this.records` array.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return data from a single query, you shouldn't use `valueChanges()`, since it doesn't return a promise.  `valueChanges` is used when you want to set up a listener for data that could change over time.

For your case, use `get()` instead, which returns a promise that resolves with the results of the query as shown [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/1413#issuecomment-356352970).

```
await this.afs.collection<Records>('records').ref.get()
```

Comment: thank you for the notice but essentially the problem still exists, because whether or not I change the method how I grab the data the problem is in the order the code is processed.